# Physics classics

Tags: resource-recommendations, history, big-list

I would like some help to find

good and detailed books on the history of physics.

Which are the classics in this domain? Which are your favorite?

Comment: See the policy on [resource recommendations](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed)

Comment: This is a very broad question. See, e.g., [my list](http://worldcat.org/profiles/Geremia10/lists/1682310?count=300&se=as&sd=asc&qt=sort_as_asc). (1) mechanics: Dugas's [_History of Mechanics_](http://worldcat.org/oclc/467891714), (2) medieval physics: Ariew's abridged translation of Duhem: [_Medieval Cosmology: Theories of Infinity, Place, Time, Void, and the Plurality of Worlds_](http://worldcat.org/oclc/12080192) (and [anything else by Duhem](http://garrigou.us.to/browse/matches/authors/154) and his followers), (3) statics: Duhem's [_Origins of Statics_](http://worldcat.org/oclc/858949468).